# gulp js gave the error when i changed my js files..| throw er

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

i build a new js file in my ng directory the user.svc.js , the contents of the file are

```
angular.module('app')
.service('UserSvc',function($http) {
var svc = this;
svc.getUser = function () {
return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users',{
headers:{'X-Auth : this.token'}
})
}
svc.login = function(username,password){
return $http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/sessions',{
username:username,password:password
}).then(function(val){
svc.token = val.data;
return svc.getUser();
})
}
})
```

the error that I am getting is:

> C:\Users\setCodesToFire\Documents\modernweb\app>gulp js
>       [00:57:06] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\modernweb\app\gulpfile.js
>      [00:57:06] Starting 'js'...
>       [00:57:06] Finished 'js' after 79 ms
>
> events.js:160
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
>       Error: app.js: error: couldn't process source due to parse error
>       Unexpected token (54:2)

can anyone tell me what is the problem.do it has to do something with the $http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the header values to object format instead of a string value

change this

```
headers:{'X-Auth : this.token'}
```

to this

```
headers: {
   'X-Auth' : 'this.token'
}
```

Comment: @Rohan Goyal nice. make sure to check it as answer if this helped

Comment: i have just created the account yesterday so it took time to reflect the answer check :)